# How to fill a Vigenère square?

Tags: tables, matrices, cryptocode

Im trying to do a [Vigenère square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), but I have to modify it several times, so
is there any way to fill it with multido or any other method, instead of tabular and by hand.

[image]

**UPDATE**
All are great answers that show me how ignorant I am.
I cant get compiled none because I get errors of  the Undefined control sequence type. But afaik, all examples are fine. I have double checked the texlive if there is something roaming out there, but I havent found anything out of order.
Sincerely I never imagined these answers.

**UPDATE 2**
For the aswer given by egreg it gets

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \NewDocumentCommand
                        {\vigenere}{}
```

So it is not recognizing the definition of the command,
and gives more blah about

```
! Missing number, treated as zero./! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l_vigenere_body_tl.
```

for the Mico/Werner answer is requiring me to install Luatex, thats supposed to be installed right in livetex.

```
! Package luacode Error: LuaTeX is required for this package. Aborting..
```

The wipet answer I dont know how to use, because I think this must be done on some .sty file.

**UPDATE 3**
The lualatex was generated succesfully as showed in the answer.
Thanks to Mico

Comment: You don't have to *modify* it as it contains all the possibilities. I guess you just don't want to type it out manually, correct?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is  the multido work with numbers not letters. And your are right, I dont have to modify it, but Im making variations so it makes variations

Comment: For the ConTeXt solution, you could compile [here](https://live.contextgarden.net/). Clean the text field, copy-paste the content below, click `typeset` and then `download the pdf-file`. As for the others, they should work with any up-to-date distribution...

Comment: You mention in an Update paragraph that you cannot get any of the answers to compile. Please be more specific as to the problems you're encountering.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio, Thanks I didnt know the site existed.

Comment: @Mico, Im working to post the errors

Comment: LuaLaTeX is definitely a part of TeXLive. But to *use* LuaLaTeX rather than the default pdfLaTeX to compile the test document. you *must* change the item in one of the pull-down menus of your editor, to select the desired version of LaTeX. Unless I completely missed it, you haven't told us so far which editor/front end you employ. Please advise.

Comment: @Mico, the editor Its just a normal text editor, so there is no option to select latex versions. You could say I just write something and launch pdflatex. But Im looking for dedicated editors

Comment: @riccs_0x - And how, precisely, do you "launch pdflatex"? Please be specific. For once we have clarity as to how you launch pdflatex, it should be easy to figure out how to launch lualatex.

Comment: @Mico, I just get rendered the lualatex option, at the end it was a matter of launching the right binary

Comment: @riccs_0x - So you *do*, in fact, not use "just a normal text editor" program but, instead, one that lets you choose the program with which to compile the document. Unfortunately, my mind-reading skills are absolutely worthless; hence, don't expect me to guess which editor you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many solutions already, but I like add some more, which I used for my currently unpublished book. It's a bit tricky, but with rather simple code and easy to read and understand, I hope you like it :-)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm]

\foreach \z [count=\zx] in {Z,...,A}{%
    \foreach \b [count=\bx] in {\z,...,Z}{%
        \node [anchor=base] (N\bx\zx) at (\bx,\zx) {\b};
    }
}

\foreach \z [count=\zx] in {A,...,Y}{%
    \foreach \b [count=\bx] in {\z,...,A}{%
        \node [anchor=base] (S\bx\zx) at (27-\bx,26-\zx) {\b};
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Its a bit tricky indeed, but at the same time this was more or less what I was thinking but never guessed the letters could be sorted like a number. Thank =)

Answer (score 12):

Fill the table one row at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{headers}{RGB}{234,232,218}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_vigenere_body_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\vigenere}{}
 {
  % make the first row
  \tl_set:Nn \l_vigenere_body_tl { \hline \rowcolor{headers} }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_vigenere_body_tl
   {
    \int_step_function:nN {26} \vigenere_first:n
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_vigenere_body_tl { \\ \hline }
  \int_step_inline:nn { 26 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_vigenere_body_tl { \bfseries \int_to_Alph:n { ##1 } }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_vigenere_body_tl
     {
      \int_step_function:nnN { ##1 } { ##1+25 } \vigenere_further:n
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_vigenere_body_tl { \\ \hline }
   }
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5pt}\sffamily
  \begin{tabular}{ | >{\columncolor{headers}}c | *{26}{c|} }
  \l_vigenere_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new:Nn \vigenere_first:n { & \exp_not:N \bfseries \int_to_Alph:n { #1 } }
\cs_new:Nn \vigenere_further:n
 {
  & \int_to_Alph:n { \int_mod:nn { #1-1 } { 26 } + 1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\vigenere

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{luacode} 
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

-- an auxiliary function
function rowprint ( t )
    for i = 1,26 do
       tex.sprint ( "&" .. t:sub(i,i) )
    end
    tex.sprint ("\\\\ \\hline")
end

-- the main function
function vigenere ()
    tex.sprint ( "\\hline" )
    -- header row
    tex.sprint ( "\\rowcolor{lightgray}" )
    for i = 1,26 do
       tex.sprint ( "&\\textbf{\\textsf{" .. s:sub(i,i) .. "}}" )
    end
    tex.sprint ("\\\\ \\hline")
    
    -- data rows (from A to Z )
    t = s
    for j=1,26 do
       t = s:sub(j) .. s:sub(1,j-1)
       tex.sprint (  "\\cellcolor{lightgray}\\textbf{\\textsf{" .. t:sub(1,1) .. "}}" )
       rowprint ( t )
    end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{27}{c|}}
   \directlua{vigenere()} 
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: A follow-up: In case the letters in entire table, and not just in the header column and row, shoul be rendered in the prevailing sans-serif font, just (a) change `"&\\textbf{\\textsf{" .. s:sub(i,i) .. "}}"` to `"&\\textbf{" .. s:sub(i,i) .. "}"`, (b) change `"\\cellcolor{lightgray}\\textbf{\\textsf{" .. t:sub(1,1) .. "}}"` to `"\\cellcolor{lightgray}\\textbf{" .. t:sub(1,1) .. "}"`, and (c) insert `\sffamily` immediately before `\begin{tabular}`.

Answer (score 10):

Another way of cycling through the alphabet using [`pgffor`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor,xcolor,eqparbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ALPH}[1]{%
  \ifnum #1>26
    \@Alph{\numexpr#1-26}%
  \else
    \@Alph{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \sffamily\footnotesize
  \centering
  \fcolorbox{black}{brown!50!white}{\eqmakebox[vignere]{\vphantom{Q}}}% Top-left box
  \foreach \Char in {1, ..., 26} {%
    \fcolorbox{black}{brown!50!white}{\eqmakebox[vignere]{\vphantom{Q}\bfseries\@Alph{\Char}}}% header
  }\\[-1pt]
  \foreach \CharA in {0, ..., 25} {%
    \fcolorbox{black}{brown!50!white}{\eqmakebox[vignere]{\vphantom{Q}\bfseries\@Alph{\numexpr\CharA + 1}}}% Left column
    \foreach \CharB in {0, ..., 25} {%
      \fbox{\eqmakebox[vignere]{\vphantom{Q}\ALPH{\numexpr\CharA + \CharB + 1}}}%
    }%
    \\[-1pt]
  }
  \par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun, another solution based on `\foreach` macro from OpTeX:

```
\def\list{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\def\cyclelist#1#2\relax{\def\list{#2#1}}
\def\fr#1{\hbox to1.3em{\hss#1\hss\vrule height10pt depth4pt}}

\vbox{
   \hbox{\ea\foreach\list \do{\hbox to1.3em{\hss\bf #1\hss}}}
   \smallskip\hrule
   \ea\foreach\list \do{%
      \hbox{\llap{\bf#1 }\vrule\ea\foreach\list \do{\fr{##1}}}
      \hrule
      \ea\cyclelist\list \relax
   }%
}

\bye
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, a ConTeXt solution:

```
%%% Funny colors
\usecolors[svg]
%%% For a smaller image
\setupbodyfont[small]
\starttext
%%% ConTeXt counterpart of standalone
\startTEXpage[offset=1pt]
%%% The actual fun
\startluacode
local uwu = {
    background = "color", 
    backgroundcolor = "darkkhaki", 
    style="\\ssbf"
}
context.bTABLE({align="middle", style = "\\ss"})
for i = 0, 26 do
    context.bTR()
    for j = 0, 26 do
        if i == 0 and j == 0 then
            context.bTD(uwu)
            context("")
        elseif i*j == 0 then
            context.bTD(uwu)
            context(string.char(64+math.max(i,j)))
        else
            context.bTD()
            context(string.char(65+(i+j-2)%26))
        end
        context.eTD()
    end
    context.eTR()
end
context.eTABLE()
\stopluacode
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

[image]